# What is the possibility of being rejected by Graduate school if a professor has already acclaimed to give me a RA offer

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I have passed several loops of evaluation by a professor, who would like to be my future advisor. He told me that he made his final decision on me and was pleased to offer me a RA position in his lab. He asked me to submit my application and he could expedite the application so that I could get the admission quickly. But I have a weakness of undergraduate GPA(3.01/4, he didnt ask for any transcript information during our connection). I'm waiting for the admission information but very uptight about the result. I'm super worried about being rejected by the graduate school because of my undergraduate gpa.

Comment: Sorry, this depends on the rules of the university.  Stack Exchange cannot help here.  You should always have a backup plan.

Comment: US? ............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing you can do is to ask the professor. Tell them you’re worried that you won’t be accepted because of your GPA, and whether it’ll be an issue.

My guess is that if a professor suggests that you join the program, and says they’ll expedite it, they know what’s the admission process and requirements. Send your application to them before you submit and ask if it looks ok, they’ll know what to do. In many departments the word of a professor who really wants someone to join carries a lot of weight, so I wouldn’t worry too much. But bottom line: communicate with the person whom you’ll be discussing many issues with for the next few years.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mister. This is quite a nice answer that I need. And the professor was like "I will start working on it tomorrow. You will hear from our staff soon regarding admission. You can expect to receive the decision and an offer letter from the Department in about 2 weeks if not longer". Is it a positive reply ?

Comment: Actually I would _not_ go back to the professor. Presumably s/he has already taken the GPA into account. If it wasn't a problem then, it won't be a problem now, and you are just making more work for the prof. If the decision lies elsewhere, then it will be evaluated elsewhere. Let it lie.

Answer (score 1):

If the Graduate School has the final say, then you will have to wait for their decision - we cannot guess their response, and probably neither can the professor.

However, if the professor has the final say and the Grad School just processes his acceptance then you should be fine, assuming there are no hidden things...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you kindly help me to check out the reply of the professor? I'm not sure if I might miss some information of it.

Comment: -1 contradictory, does not mention that the rules vary between universities

Comment: I'm applying for PhD program in the states. How can I get to know the rules of a certain university

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist are you assuming that the professor is working for several universities? Or just being obtuse? OP is reasonably clear, but not explicit by mentioning the name of the institution, that this is one application to one professor with acceptance....

Comment: @OwltsanWong check out the university / institution website - they will usually say...

Comment: I'm not bothering to elaborate because I'm sure this will get closed.  You stated two contradictory rules, and we don't know which one applies to this situation.  Which one applies depends on the university.  You didn't explain that both answers are plausible.  Without additional detail your answer has no information.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist The answer starts with "If ..." and the second para starts with "However..." so I assume you must have a problem with English....

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist His answer looks good :-)

Comment: Generally in the US, even when the prof has the power to choose their student and the school basically just rubber-stamps it, the school still technically has the "final say". Surprises can happen and the school's decision will be the final one, not the prof's. Still the prof can certainly give more than a guess as to the outcome, just not a 100% guarantee.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, I think you are being excessively picky here. I certainly didn't misunderstand the intent of the answer. Policies differ. What is hard or "contradictory" about that? Bad call. Go to the replay.

Comment: @Buffy I agree with you that policies differ, but the information is missing from the answer.  The asker does not know it, or else they would not have asked an ineffective question.